# Regex filter escape

Tags: javascript

I got this from a random person, he told me you could run an XSS by 'passing' the filter  :

```
function safeFunc(str) {
   if (str.replace(/(?:\d+\.?\d*(?:e\d+)?)| /g, '')) {
       return null;
     }
   return eval(str);
  }
```

Notice: you need your string to be fully 'replaced' by the regex filter in order to get to the eval, so it's kind of a backwards riddle. I tried for hours and couldn't find an answer, I use this site:
[This site](https://www.regextester.com/) helps with the regex.
I need it to evaluate and alert 1  (or anything else you can alert)
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your post. You've posted it here and therefore agreed to have it hosted here. If you want it removed for some reason, flag it for moderator attention and describe the issue. Edit: I've flagged it for you, but if you want to explain your reasoning please flag it yourself as well. Until a  moderator decides on the action to take, I'll undo any further vandalizing that I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2**: the question has been changed since this answer has posted. The regex in the original question was `/(?:Math(?:\.\w+)?)|[()+\-*/&|^%<>=,?:]|(?:\d+\.?\d*(?:e\d+)?)| /g`.

A possible answer, <del>does NOT work with properly-designed CSP (uses `Function()`)</del> you have `eval()` so `'unsafe-eval'` must be in effect:

```js
Math=Math.toString(),Math=Math.constructor,Math.code=Math.fromCharCode(97)+Math.fromCharCode(108)+Math.fromCharCode(101)+Math.fromCharCode(114)+Math.fromCharCode(116)+Math.fromCharCode(40)+Math.fromCharCode(49)+Math.fromCharCode(41),Math.constructor(Math.code)()
```

**EDIT**: @Niet the Dark Absol reminded me that `String.fromCharCode` could be simplified to:

```
Math=Math.toString(),Math=Math.constructor,Math.code=Math.fromCharCode(97,108,101,114,116,40,49,41),Math.constructor(Math.code)()
```

Detailed explanation:

1. `Math = Math.toString()` - get a String instance;
2. `Math = Math.constructor` - get the `String` function, thus `Math === String`;
3. `Math.code = Math.fromCharCode(97, 108, 101, 114, 116, 40, 49, 41)` - get the code string (i.e. `'alert(1)'`) by `String.fromCharCode()`, you could replace this with the code you wanted to inject;
4. `Math.constructor(Math.code)()` - `Math.constructor` is `Function`, thus executing `Function('alert(1)')()`.

Comment: I think you can greatly simplify the payload with `Math.fromCharCode(97,108,101...)` to build the string.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why it changed my regex, I will try to fix it however my site is broken now so anything can happen